# How to find the maximum of $\Phi: [0,1] \to \mathbb R, \quad x \mapsto L e^{-2Lx} \int_0^x | f(t)- g(t) | \, \mathrm{d} t$?

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

> Let $f,g \in \mathcal C^0([0,1],\mathbb R)$ and $L \ge 1$. We endow $\mathcal C^0([0,1],\mathbb R)$ with the sup norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. Consider $$\Phi: [0,1] \to \mathbb R, \quad x \mapsto L e^{-2Lx} \int_0^x | f(t)- g(t) | \, \mathrm{d} t$$ Find the maximum of $\Phi$.

In order to find the maximum, I take the derivative of $\Phi$ and compute the values of $\Phi$ at the critical points and at $0$ and $1$. After that. I'm unable to compare those values. Could you please shed me some light how to finish the task? Thank you so much!

---

Because $\Phi \in \mathcal C^1([0,1],\mathbb R)$, the maximum is attained at critical points or at $0$ or at $1$. We have $$\begin{aligned} \Phi'(x) &= -2L^2 e^{-2Lx} \int_0^x | f(t)- g(t) | \, \mathrm{d} t + L e^{-2Lx} | f(x)- g(x) | \\ &= L e^{-2Lx} \left (| f(x)- g(x) | - 2L \int_0^x | f(t)- g(t) | \, \mathrm{d} t \right )\end{aligned}$$

If $\bar x$ is a critical point, then $\Phi'(\bar x) = 0$ and consequently $$\frac{1}{2} | f(\bar x)- g(\bar x) | = L \int_0^{\bar x} | f(t)- g(t) | \, \mathrm{d} t$$

Then $$\Phi(\bar x) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-2L \bar x} | f(\bar x)- g(\bar x) |$$

It follows that $\Phi (0)=0$ and $$\Phi(\bar x)= \frac{1}{2} e^{-2L \bar x} | f(\bar x)- g(\bar x) |$$ and $$\Phi(1) = L e^{-2L} \int_0^1 | f(t)- g(t) | \, \mathrm{d} t$$

Comment: Hi @GeorgeDewhirst, I'm only interested in the maximum value. Is there any way to compare $\Phi(0), \Phi(\bar x),\Phi(1)$?

Comment: I think we need to prove more facts about $\bar{x}$ before we can compare $\Phi(\bar{x})$ with $\Phi(1)$

Comment: After many failed attempts, I agree with you @GeorgeDewhirst :(

Comment: what have you tried